# How to reset my environmental path to default in visual studio 19? I'm getting the following error even when using Atatas DriverSetup.AutoSetUp()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, atata

How can I reset my environmental path to default in Visual Studio 2019? Because I'm getting the following error even when using Atatas DriverSetup.AutoSetUp():

> Session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
> Current browser version is 90.0.4430.72 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)

Even though I'm using this code:

```
DriverSetup.AutoSetUp(BrowserNames.Chrome);

ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
```

So there must be something with my path right? I mean this code works and the drivers or automation runs completely fine in my other projects, so I must of tweaked something by accident in this project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it finds another `chromedriver.exe` in the project build folder. WebDriver first tries to find `chromedriver.exe` in the directory of the currently executing assembly and only then looks at PATH directories.

Do you use specific NuGet package for `ChromeDriver` in addition to `Atata.WebDriverSetup` in your project? If so, please remove it. You can also check your `bin/Debug` build folder for `chromedriver.exe`.